# how to create authentication-manager with multiple states

Tags: spring, spring-security

how to create the authentication-manager using database ?

users-by-username-query="SELECT a AS username, b AS password, userstatus AS enabled.
this userstatus has multiple values.0,1,2,3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use if for query (assumption:  userstatus 0 is disabled and another is enabled):

```
SELECT a AS username, b AS password, if(userstatus=0,0,1) AS enabled
```

u can add another if statement inside.

Comment: need to get that userstatus value as well

Answer (score 0):

What do the values in your userstatus filed represent? It is more than a binary enabled/disabled flag, but it's unclear what it exactly means.

Check if you can map these values to the properties of the `UserDetails` interface (enabled, account expired, account locked, credentials expired). If so, you only have to override `JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername()` in a subclass, so that it creates a `User` object according to the `userstatus` filed in the database. Then configure this customized sublclass as the `UserDetailsService`:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="YourCustomJdbcDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Other components of Spring Security will then make sure that the user can only get authenticated if it is enabled, not locked, etc.

Comment: 0 - deactive,1- active,2-one of the group

Comment: Mixing account status and group membership information in the same field is not the best idea. You might be better off creating your user database according to the user schema specified in the Spring Security documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-schema.html
Then you don't have to customize anything, default implementations will just work out of the box.